# не работает getAttribute

Tags: javascript

я только начал учить js. при клике на элемент нужно открыть модальное окно, но возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined. onload function я поставил, но эта ошибка не исчезает.`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < closeModal.length; i++) {
    var closeAttr = closeModal[i].getAttribute('data-close');
    closeModal[i].onclick = function closeModalWindow() {
      var modalWindows = document.getElementsByClassName('works-description');
      for (var j = 0; j < modalWindows.length; j++) {
        var attributes = modalWindows[j].getAttribute('data-window');
        if (closeAttr == attributes) {
          modalWindows[j].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var openElement = document.getElementsByClassName('openingFigure');
  for (var s = 0; s < openElement.length; s++) {
    openElement[s].onclick = function() {
      var dataOpenAttr = openElement[s].getAttribute('data-open');
      if (dataOpenAttr == attributes) {
        modalWindows[j].style.display = 'flex';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.close {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 22px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
}
.works-description h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.works-description img {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 316px;
}
.works-description {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    display: none;
}
.works-description-block {
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #94969E;
    width: 70%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.works-description-text {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.works-description-text h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 546;
}
.works-description-text p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.works-description-text a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #94969E;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #94969E;
    width: 240px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure class="batsam-figure openingFigure" data-open="0" id="batsam">
  <figcaption>
    <h2>Batsam</h2>
    <p>Дизайн, верстка</p>
  </figcaption>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
</figure>
<!--само окно-->
```

`

Comment: А где инициализируются closeModal?

Comment: не доглядел, спасибо